# Image not able to pop up when using Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Although I have differentiated between the modals, only the first modal works but the second modal pops up the image for the first modal although the source image is that of the second modal. Can someone please assist me in sorting this issue out?

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/arnold200x200.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Amino X</h3>
      <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">GHS 200</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal AminoX-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="img/arnold.png" data-title="My First Caption" data-toggle="modal" />
        <h4 class="modal-title">Amino X</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="img/arnold.png" width="350px" class="img-thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/amino_x200x200.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" />
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>Amino X</h3>
      <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">GHS 200</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal AminoX-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="img/amino_x200x200.png" data-title="My Second Caption" data-toggle="modal" />
        <h4 class="modal-title">Amino X</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="img/aminoBig.png" width="350px" class="img-thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal2">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the JavaScript code that uses the modals so we can see what might be wrong with it?

Comment: You have set both data-target="#modal1" ?

Comment: i have already posted that code @Fran

Comment: Yes i know that so what do you proposed i do @David?

Comment: @Sleeper I don't see any code, only markup. You tagged the question with JavaScript and jQuery, I assume there is code (not HTML Markup) you use to open the modals?

Comment: could you please check now @sleeper can you see the code now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference modal1 in both links,update:

```
data-target="#modal2"
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmhq51jf/)

Comment: it is still giving the same error even when the data-target is changed to #modal2

Comment: I thought you're problem was that both links opened the first modal, I never saw you're javascript just html

Comment: the javascript i am using is that of bootstrap

Comment: Test the fiddle in my answer and see that the first image opens the first modal and the second image the second modal.

Comment: the problem has not been rectified @David it still gives me the same feedback as before

Comment: The first modal works fine the first image pops up just like it should but when you click on the second image , the pop up of the first image is the one that pops up @David

Comment: @Sleeper Glad it worked out for you, please consider upvote/mark my answer.